# Sending data received from one socket.io server to a web socket client

Tags: socket.io

I'm starting to use socket.io and I have a problem that I can't solve so far

I have two nodejs running, one is the socket.io data server and the other one is going to interact with web clients

I need to get data from the server and send it to my web clients, the problem is I can't emit data to the clients outside the 'on connect'

I think is better to explain it with a simple example

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:12000');
const SocketIO = require('socket.io');
const app = require('../app');

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);

// client socket, this is a regular message from
// the server running on port 12000, it works
socket.on('msg_from_server', data => {
  console.log(data);
});

// server socket
const io = SocketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (s) => {
  // this works
  s.emit('msg_to_client', {data: 'xxxx'})

  // this doesn't works
  socket.on('msg_from_server', data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket` client for server on port 12000 and socket from  `io.on('connection', (socket)` both are different. But you are mixing them both.Do something like this:

```
 const Socket_12000 = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:12000');
    const SocketIO = require('socket.io');
    const app = require('../app');

    const server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port);

    // client socket
    socket.on('msg_from_server', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    // server socket
    const io = SocketIO(server);

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      // this works
      socket.emit('msg_to_client', {data: 'xxxx'})

      // this doesn't works
      Socket_12000.on('msg_from_server', data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
```

I have created a basic gist depicting the problem/solution please commant if you are looking something else.
https://gist.github.com/sandeepp2016/bb1946bcbeb2f11d57bc3aa2e44c158e

Comment: this is the exact same code I pasted above, I just forgot to change the name on the socket.io-client, I updated the code above but still doesn't work

Comment: it doesn't matter the code of the other socket (12000), the server only send data that the client receive with this indentificator 'msg_from_server', in the example you can see the comment "this works", it works because the server(12000) is sending correct data, so I need to receive that data and send it to the web clients connected to the nodejs that is running the code I pasted before

Comment: `socket.emit('msg_to_client', {data: 'xxxx'})`  is data to web clients if I am not wrong?

Comment: `Socket_12000.on('msg_from_server', data` will only work if server 12000 is emitting  data for that event. that's why I asked to put server 12000 code. it will give more clarity.

Comment: yes the server is emitting data, the server code would be like in your gist

Comment: @SandeepPatel I did a new project with minimum requirements, just to test your code and it works, I don't know why is not working in my original project, which have a lot of other libraries, but now I know that the code works, thank you very much